# Swift1.2 compiler error in initialization function of structure

Tags: struct, enums, compiler-errors, swift

I have the following code for handling JSON easier. However I get an compiler error in debug as well as release mode: `Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault 11`. The line where the compiler apparently fails compiling is the first line of the initialization method. I also tried several different ways (nested function, assigning  the closure to another variable first and so on) but the compiler wasn't able to get it to work. Is there any way to fix this? Thanks for your help

```
enum JSONValue {
case JSONString(String)
case JSONNumber(Double)
case NIL(NilLiteralConvertible)
case JSONArray(Array<JSON>)
case JSONDictionary(Dictionary<String, JSON>)
}

struct JSON {
private let value: JSONValue

init(_ object: AnyObject?) {
    value = { () -> JSONValue in
        switch object {
        case _ where object is String:
            return .JSONString(object as! String)
        case _ where object is NSNumber:
            return .JSONNumber((object as! NSNumber).doubleValue)
        case _ where object is Array<AnyObject>:
            var array = [JSON]()
            let original = object as! [AnyObject]
            for item in original {
                array += [JSON(item)]
            }
            return .JSONArray(array)
        case _ where object is [String: AnyObject]:
            var dictionary = [String: JSON]()
            let original = object as! [String: AnyObject]
            for item in original {
                dictionary[item.0] = JSON(item.1)
            }
            return .JSONDictionary(dictionary)
        default:
            return .NIL(nil)
        }
    }()
}

var dictionaryKeyArray: [String] {
    switch self.value {
    case .JSONDictionary(let dictionary):
        var result = [String]()
        for item in dictionary.keys {
            result.append(item)
        }
        return result
    default:
        fatalError("no dictionary")
    }
}

var jsonArray: [JSON] {
    switch self.value {
    case .JSONArray(let array):
        return array
    default:
        fatalError("no array")
    }
}

var stringArray: [String] {
    switch self.value {
    case .JSONArray(let array):
        var result = [String]()
        for item in array {
            result.append(item.stringValue)
        }
        return result
    default:
        fatalError("no string array")
    }
}

var doubleValue: Double {
    switch self.value {
    case .JSONNumber(let double):
        return double
    default:
        fatalError("no double value")
    }
}

var intValue: Int {
    switch self.value {
    case .JSONNumber(let int):
        return Int(int)
    default:
        fatalError("no integer value")
    }
}

var stringValue: String {
    switch self.value {
    case .JSONString(let string):
        return string
    default:
        fatalError("no string value")
    }
}

var isNil: Bool {
    switch self.value {
    case .NIL(_):
        return true
    default:
        return false
    }
}

subscript(index: Int) -> JSON {
    switch self.value {
    case .JSONArray(let array) where array.count < index:
        return array[index]
    default:
        return JSON(nil)
    }
}

subscript(key: String) -> JSON {
    switch self.value {
    case .JSONDictionary(let dictionary) where dictionary[key] != nil:
        return dictionary[key]!
    default:
        return JSON(nil)
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler should not segfault, no matter how wrong the source code is,
so you could write a bug report to Apple in any case.

But the problem is that defining

```
enum JSONValue {
    // ...
    case NIL(NilLiteralConvertible)
    // ...
}
```

does not mean that `JSONValue.NIL(nil)` is a valid enumeration value.

Types conforming to `NilLiteralConvertible` are those which can be
*initialized* with `nil`, for example optionals:

```
let opt : Int? = nil
```

So `JSONValue.NIL(Optional<Int>(0))` would be a valid enumeration value. But that is probably not what you wanted.

I think you should just define the enumeration as

```
enum JSONValue {
    case JSONString(String)
    case JSONNumber(Double)
    case NIL     // <- instead of NIL(NilLiteralConvertible)
    case JSONArray(Array<JSON>)
    case JSONDictionary(Dictionary<String, JSON>)
}
```

and then replace `.NIL(nil)` by `.NIL` in your code. At least it
does compile with this change.